# Pass parameter to SQL file from within another SQL file

Tags: sql, oracle, arguments, sqlplus

I thought for sure there would be an SO question on this, but I haven't been able to find one.

I have 2 SQL files, `myFile1.sql` and `myFile2.sql`. `myFile1.sql` calls `myFile2.sql` like so:

```
-- In myFile1.sql:
@scripts/myFile2
```

This works with no problem, but now I'd like to pass an argument to the file. I've tried doing the following, with no success (results in a File Not Found exception):

```
@scripts/myFile2 'ImAnArgument'
```

Does anyone know what the syntax would be to do this?

Comment: Have you tried it without the parameter? If so does it run as expected?

Comment: It runs without issue. I have been varying setting a parameter to `&1` or not to see what happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many attempts, I wasn't able to pass a parameter in (and I still don't understand why not). But here is what I did to get the same affect:

```
-- In myFile1.sql:
DEFINE my_arg = 'ImAnArgument';
@scripts/myFile2
```

Then

```
-- In myFile2.sql 
-- Do stuff using the variable my_arg, such as
SELECT my_arg FROM my_table;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing your problem is that `scripts/myFile2.sql` is a relative path from the script it is located in. If that is so, then it is following that path from the directory where SQL*Plus was started (the current working directory). If this is the problem, then it's not the parameter that is the issue, but rather that SQL*Plus can't find the file. In this case, you should use `@@`, which invokes the path relative to the file it's located in.

---

The parameter should work just as you proposed ([documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a90842/ch13.htm#1006685)). Parameters provided when invoking a file are placed into substitution variables (rather than bind variables) and can be referenced by using an ampersand followed by the argument number. In your example, `'ImAnArgument'` would be `&1`.